# In unity probuilder, how to create new face with selected vertex

Tags: unity-game-engine

I use unity official asset [probuilder](https://unity3d.com/unity/features/worldbuilding/probuilder)

see my gif, I select hold 4 vertexes, I hope create new face so I click "Fill Hole", but not face is created
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've never used probuilder, but in other 3d max app you will need to delete the inner polygons that to be able to cap that face.  select all the polygons in the "well" and delete, you will now have a hole to fill

[GIF]
[[image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3My9.gif)

Answer (score 0):

update

I find a complex but accurate way to do this

unity editor > Tools > Probuilder > editor > open vertex position editor
when i select vertex, position editor

put selected positions to txt file

unity editor > tools > probuilder > editor > open new shape editor > shape selector > custom

build face with positions in txt

**attention**: "Custom" point order is very strange, for ex, "Custom" to build cube, the point order is, top-left, top-right, bottom-left, bottom-right, in my understanding, the correct order is:

in x-z axis face, image put point in Scene to build more near "parallel" x axis edge
put edge point from x axis < 0(left) side to x axis > 0(right) side, and then use same way to build other "parallel"  x axis edge

select my created face and old object, probuilder toolbar > Merge Objects to merge them into one

above way I use do all with ProBuilder API since it's opensource but not document, but filling face is rare case, so I think do it in probuilder gui is enongh

**old answer**

my tmp solution is use probuilder > New Poly Shape to use mouse click 4 vertexs and manually make face, but it's not perfect, it has seam in edge

Comment: I think you're complicating things, hold i'll make a video

Comment: @comphonia I cannot always make crossable hole, in my case, I just wanna fill the seam, in you solution, if there are too many inner faces, that will more complex than my way

Answer (score 0):

As of probuilder 4, you can achieve this very quickly without using 'fill hole'. Fill Hole is useful, but not for this.

1. Enter edge select mode and select an edge containing two of the vertices you wish to make a face out of.
2. Extrude the edge (ctrl + e or 'extrude edges') to the general area of the third vertex.
3. Enter vertex select mode and select the third vertex, then the two vertices from step two and any others you want to add.
4. Click the collapse vertices button and ensure "Collapse at first" is enabled (it will stay enabled until you disable it). The shortcut is alt + C.

You can also use this technique & the alt+c ctrl+e keys to quickly weld coincident vertices and quickly draft complex level geometry. You can also use this to quickly bridge edges even if they have a different vertex count.

With the Probuilder API, you can easily make an editor script to automate this process & assign a special shortcut to it. If you can operate the Unity API, you can operate the probuilder API.